# Unable to Load UITest dll Assembly

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am getting an error "Unable to load UItest.dll Assembly" in Win App.
I am trying to launch my Coded UI test methods through small win app developed in VS C#. Please note there is no build error in both the projects(WinApp & Coded UI Test Project).

I am adding .dll of my coded ui test project into win app project & with creating an object of test class, I want to access the test methods [Please refer attached screenshot of StartExceution button click code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoITM.jpg).

Note:- I am successfully launch the test methods with d use of MStest.exe,
Please help me into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call CodedUI Test methods directly from other methods within an assembly. The MSTest Framework actually uses some bizzare reflection magic that prevents you from doing so.

Instead what you can do (not saying you should) is:

- Create a delegate for "test helper methods" if they have a common signature.
- Change your existing test methods to only call those delegates rather than performing the test themselves.
- Call those delegates from the button click event methods as well if you want to do so.

Keep in mind that there is no way you're ever going to be able to launch a test with results and reporting a la MStest from a button unless the button itself calls MSTest.exe